# Open new Tab with L.EasyButton

Tags: leaflet, tab

I added an L.EasyButton to my map. Now I want it - by clicking - to open a new tab with a specific address.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
L.easyButton, function(btn, map){
    onclick="window.open('http://www.website.com/page')" 
}).addTo(map);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a different language than JavaScript? Your code syntax seems weird.

You would simply do something like:

```js
L.easyButton('fa-globe', function () {
    window.open("http://www.website.com/page");
}).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/45/

Comment: This still won't open a new tab in every case. To specify the target as a new tab, you have to provide `_blank` as a second argument to `window.open`. Like `window.open("http://www.website.com/page", "_blank");`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Any example when it would not open a new window / tab? It seems it should be the [default behaviour](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-open).

Comment: Interestingly, I could not come up with a valid case, as `_blank` seems to be the default behaviour indeed. It seems like, I mixed it up with the anchor element's `target` property, for which `_self` is the default value.